# What is a "concerned member of the public"?

Tags: meaning

What is a "concerned member of the public"? Does it mean someone who is enthusiastic for public affairs?

Are there some words can be used to take place of it?

Comment: I know it used as something meaning "a member of the public who is concerned about the aforementioned topic". Implicating it is a topic "for everybody to relate to", something the public has an interest in. And, although that person has no more relation to the topic than anybody else, it is concerned.

Comment: @sky - I would take it to mean that it's a topic that _some_ or _many_ people will relate to, but not necessarily "everybody." Those who sign petitions, march in protests, actively work for political causes, and are very likely to vote are "concerned members of the public." Those same folks may have relatives or neighbors who are much less concerned, if not downright indifferent.

Comment: I think I just didn't manage to describe it right. Usually of course just some people are concerned, but it is often used to undermine that it is about a topic "everybody" could/should be concerned of.

Comment: @skymninge - Yes, very true - LOL - concerned members of the public always seem to think everyone else should be as concerned as they are.

Comment: In the US, *concerned citizen* is common parlance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned), *concerned* can mean:

> having an interest or involvement in something

And *the public* is:

> the people of a country, state, etc.

So, a *concerned member of the public* is any citizen who takes an interest in the topic being discussed.

Comment: Have you ever heard of idioms? Do you know, that combination of two words can mean something absolutely new? Your "logic" is irrelevant. According to you, "give in" would mean to give something inside somebody, instead of surrendering.

Comment: @Gangnus, Feel free to explain how I am wrong, since as far as I can tell my answer is fairly similar to your own.

Comment: The author of the question, being not English, has found, that the word "concerned" has got a meaning, sometimes mentioned in dictionaries, but not as a separate one. And you haven't noticed it also, I am afraid. I mean concerned not in something special, but concerned in some important to the speaker, non explicitly specified things. He is not sure if he is correct. And your combination is not an answer. At least, I see it all so. (Maybe, it is me, who hadn't catch up these fine meanings precisely)

Comment: @Gangnus I don't think the expression "concerned member of the public" counts as an idiom, not at least in the strict definition you are implying.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that characters in film and TV use it as an explanation for what the person being questioned might see as "undue interest" so maybe it's a way to say that it's a general concern a citizen could have based on publicly available information rather than for some other ulterior motive, sort of like how the government is held to account by the public as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The term "concerned member of the public" is usually:

- used by or about a person looking for people doing bad things.
- used by or about a person telling someone in authority about someone doing bad things.

Often this is a euphemism used by the above to make it look like they are doing those things because they want to be a good citizen, or good member of the community.  But really they want to get someone in trouble they don't like.

And of course, authorities may ask for something like "Any concerned member of the public can call XXX-XXXX to report any information about this accident, incident, robbery, crime," etc.  In this case it is not usually meant euphemistically but literally.

Comment: Could you provide examples that illustrate the two different meanings, please?

Answer (score -1):

A "concerned girl" is a girl, concerned in something concrete we know about. A "concerned citizen" can very probably have that other meaning - a proactive citizen. All depends on the context. A concerned public member I would feel as having only the second meaning.